# Unable to take screenshot (JPEG) of a defined range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to take a screenshot of a range with a button and put the JPEG in the same folder. The defined range is 'header'

It runs fine for some time then all of sudden I get one of the following errors.

Vba code:

```
Sub CommandB_Click()
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yy_mm_dd_hh_mm")
Const FName As String = "Screenshotzx.jpg"
Dim pic_rng As Range
Dim ShTemp As Worksheet
Dim ChTemp As Chart
Dim PicTemp As Picture
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set pic_rng = ActiveSheet.Range("header")
Set ShTemp = Worksheets.Add
Charts.Add
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShTemp.Name
Set ChTemp = ActiveChart
pic_rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
ChTemp.Paste
Set PicTemp = Selection
With ChTemp.Parent
.Width = 1400
.Height = 720
End With
ChTemp.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Scrnsht.jpg", FilterName:="jpg"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ShTemp.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Error Code 13 Type Mismatch** on the following line

```
Set PicTemp = Selection
```

**Error Code 1004** on the following line

`pic_rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture`

Comment: The problem is probably your use of `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveChart`, and `Selection`. Also, the way you add `ChTemp` - adding a chart sheet, moving the active chart, etc. is very roundabout. If you have Excel 2013 or later (as I hope you do), you can use [`AddChart2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shapes-addchart2-method-excel).

Comment: Thanks Ben. Could you please provide an example? 
I don't use VBA that often.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this (gets rid of unused variables `dt` and `Fname` and avoids `ActiveSheet`, `ActiveChart` and `Selection`)? Note that this uses `AddChart2`, which is only available in Excel 2013 and later.

```
Sub SaveRangeAsJPEG()
    Dim pic_rng As Range
    Dim ChTemp As Chart
    Dim ShTemp As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set pic_rng = Sheets("YourSheetName").Range("header") 'change to your sheet name
    Set ShTemp = Worksheets.Add
    Set ChTemp = ShTemp.Shapes.AddChart2.Chart

    pic_rng.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture
    ChTemp.Paste

    With ChTemp.ChartArea
        .Width = 1400
        .Height = 720
    End With

    ChTemp.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Scrnsht.jpg", FilterName:="jpg"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ShTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Comment out the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` and step through the code with F8 - can you isolate which step is not producing the desired results?

Comment: When I disable Screen Updating it does nothing. Still blank sheet.

Comment: But, when I disable DisplayAlerts.. it gives an err https://prnt.sc/jsky6x

Comment: On clicking debug it shows error on this line ChTemp.Export Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Scrnsht.jpg", FilterName:="jpg"

Comment: That line is unchanged from your original code - are you sure the path is correct? What does `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Scrnsht.jpg"` give you?

Comment: Or did you have the previous (blank) "Scrnsht.jpg" file open when you re-ran the macro?

Comment: And yeah, that path is correct as excel is able to write the file (38 kb) there but I believe it's not copying the range maybe.

Comment: Did you try stepping through with F8?

Comment: I tried it now. When I run the macro it asks do you want to delete the sheet? which is already a blank sheet. So the range is not getting copied as I said before. I have 13 modules in the sheet. Maybe there is some conflict in the timing. I have to go through that again. Will let you know if it gets resolved. Thanks BigBen!!